# How to hide html comments in chrome dev tools?

Tags: html, google-chrome, comments, google-chrome-devtools

In Firebug, there's an option to toggle/view HTML comments:

[image: toggle HTML comments in Firebug]

Is there any way to do this in Chrome Developer Tools?

Comment: I've searched everywhere, and the only way I can think of is to write my own chrome developer tools extension.

Comment: If you do this, I'd be very keen to use it. It becomes very wearing to delete all the comment nodes every refresh when dealing with div soup.

Comment: This now exists *(thanks **jbyrd** )* - see [Arunabh Ghosh's answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42950240/1447509) for where to find in latest Chrome vers

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I would like to give a more detailed answer to this question. Note that this answer corresponds to chrome version - 56.0.2924.87 (64-bit).

Let's take a demo site - [Django Demo Projects](http://django-comments-xtd.readthedocs.io/en/latest/example.html).

On inspection you can see that there are a few comments near the top:
[image]

Click the `Customize and control DevTools` option (the three dots near the top right corner):
[image]

Select the settings option. You should be able to see `Show HTML comments`:
[image]

Disable to `Show HTML comments` to remove comments. Now all comments are hidden!
[image]

Thank you!

Answer (score 7):

This option is available in the chrome dev tools settings panel (Preferences > Elements > Show HTML comments).

Comment: What version of Chrome? I'm on Version 53.0.2785.143 m, and I don't see that option: https://snag.gy/IHuU4n.jpg

Comment: It is available on Version 54.0.2840.59 for MacOs. I assumed it has been introducted for a while. If you can't update, check also the dev version of Chrome, [Chrome Canary](https://www.google.fr/chrome/browser/canary.html) which contains beta features.

Comment: I see it now! I'm on Chrome version 55.0.2883.87 m.

Answer (score 3):

As of Chrome version 35.0.1916.114, there is no way to hide comments in the Elements panel. As @jbyrd suggested, someone will need to write an extension or the Chrome dev team needs to notice this thread.

Comment: Can't believe this hasn't happened yet.

Comment: Well, this isn't the right place to submit feature requests. The team that works on the DevTools will never see it. The way to get the request seen is to submit a new issue at the [chromium bug tracker](http://crbug.com). Then we can get the right people to look at the request and go from there.

Comment: See [Raphael Larrinaga's answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40126363/422845) - after I submitted a feature request, it's now a preference in the latest Chrome!